# How to generate html report with gradle 1.12?

Tags: android, testing, gradle, automated-tests

Anyone knows how to generate test report for gradle 1.12?

I'm using gradle 1.12. My Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. using Espresso test framework. My test run but doesn't generate html report.

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    maven { url 'http://JRAF.org/static/maven/2' }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    ...
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    def Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('version.properties')))
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.android.apps'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionName versionProps['name']
        versionCode versionProps['code'].toInteger()
        testApplicationId 'my.test'
        testInstrumentationRunner 'com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner'
    }
    android {
        useOldManifestMerger true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

I run my test using shell script
Here's my shell script:

```
# Clean and Build the project
gradle clean build
# Install apk to device
gradle installDebug installDebugTest

# Run specific test
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am instrument -e class my.test.RunTestSuite -w my.test/com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner
```

The result in command prompt:

```
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 55.003 secs

my.test.TestActionBar:.
Test results for GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner$BridgeTestRunner=.
Time: 32.519

OK (1 test)
```

If fail

```
Test results for GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner$BridgeTestRunner=.E
Time: 29.595

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Gradle [userguide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) by navigating to *Example 23.14. Creating a unit test report for subprojects*

Also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963554/how-to-make-gradle-build-produce-html-test-report-instead-of-xml-default)