# How to make Gradle build produce HTML test report instead of XML default?

Tags: html, junit, gradle, report

Currently I build my Gradle app by running `gradle clean build`. This exercises JUnit tests and produces XML test results in my project under `build/test-results`. I would like to configure my `build.gradle` file to produce HTML test results (instead of the XML default). Is this possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
test {
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }               
}
```

To figure this out on your own, start from `Test` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html), then drill down into (the type for) `reports`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Niederwieser (+1) - I think you are referring to [this link](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:reports) which I had already found prior to posting my question. **The root problem is this: that link doesn't mention the `junitXml.enabled` or `html.enabled` properties at all...so how in the world is anybody supposed to know they exist?!?**

Comment: Click the next link (`TestTaskReports`). What's missing in my answer that caused you not to accept it?

Comment: Thanks again @Peter Niederwieser (+1) - I guess I'm just stunned that this isn't documented anywhere else besides API docs, which one then has to *manually infer* property names from (using Camel Casing).

Comment: Usually these things are documented in the DSL reference, but sometimes they aren't.

Comment: Anyone knows how this would be for android gradle scripts ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect under JUnit 5, even for JUnit 4-based tests.

Comment: where do I place this?

Comment: this worked for me after long day of search (my project is kotlin + spring boot + gradle + Junit -jupiter)

Comment: In more recent versions of Gradle, the test and coverage (JaCoCo plugin) both use `required` instead of `enabled`. For example: `html.required = true`