# jenkins + ghprbhook - how to set status message?

Tags: github, jenkins, gradle

I've installed the [ghprbhook](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) plugin to my jenkins system. It triggers when I send a PR but isn't setting the result text properly. The 'success' / 'failure' message is working but the rest is `Build finished. No test results found.`

The disconnect seems to be between the gradle build plugin and the ghprbhook service. In the ghprbhook [source](https://github.com/janinko/ghprb/blob/85eec74b75ade958e533eba8988427c3d3950b86/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/ghprb/manager/impl/GhprbBaseBuildManager.java) it's checking for **hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction** to be set and apparently it isn't.

Question:

Is it possible to have gradle set the appropriate values? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was looking in the wrong place. The way to get useful values to show up in github is to add the **Publish JUnit Test Result Report** post-build step to your jenkins job. Assuming that you have gradle and junit [outputting xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963554/how-to-make-gradle-build-produce-html-test-report-instead-of-xml-default) you should see the output in github when you build.