# Add Junit Pioneer @Issue annotation info to Gradle Test Report

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit, junit5

I put [@Issue](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/issue/) annotation from [JUnit Pioneer library](https://junit-pioneer.org/) on my test suites. Look at the code snippet below:

```java
@Test
@Issue("TY-5232")
void shouldReturn200IfTryingToCreateNewAccountWithAvailableName() {...}
```

Also, I'm using [Gradle Test Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963554/how-to-make-gradle-build-produce-html-test-report-instead-of-xml-default) to produce HTML report of tests' results.
I wonder is to possible to add information about issue to the Gradle test report? I'd like to see which test belongs to particular task.

Perhaps I need to register some callback but I didn't find specific way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem differently.

First, I create custom `IssueProccessor` that implements the corresponding interface in JUnit Pioneer library.

```java
public class SimpleIssueProcessor implements IssueProcessor {

    @Override
    public void processTestResults(List<IssueTestSuite> issueTestSuites) { 
        /* this callback receives information about all tests marked with `@Issue` annotation */ 
    }

}
```

Then I register it as Java ServiceLoader so JUnit uses the instance of the class during its lifecycle. In order to do that, I create a file `src/test/resources/META-INF/services/org.junitpioneer.jupiter.IssueProcessor` with the content below:

```
com.my.company.SimpleIssueProcessor
```

This is the fully qualified name of the `SimpleIssueProcessor` implementation.

And finally, I create another file `src/test/resources/META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener` with content:

```
org.junitpioneer.jupiter.issue.IssueExtensionExecutionListener
```

That's the JUnit `TestExecutionListener` provided by JUnit Pioneer library that delegates information to `IssueProcessor` implementation.

---

And that's basically it. Now you process the information in `SimpleIssueProcessor` callback and build any documentation you want.